# Textarea returns undefined while fetching value with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to fetch string from a textarea which has a unique ID(its not repeated anywhere else) but it returns undefined in every case.

```
<textarea placeholder="Type note contents here" id="newNoteText" ></textarea>
```

The jquery part for the same is:

```
$("#saveNoteBtn").click(function () {

        var n = new NewNote();
        n.note = $("#newNoteText").val();
        n.date = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", new Date());
        n.name = notesViewModel["NoteCreator"]();

        notesViewModel.Notes.push(n);
        notes.save();

    });
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with code. Have you tested wit with `cosole.log()` or `alert()`?

Comment: have you tried $("textarea#newNoteText").val();

Comment: $("textarea#newNoteText").val(); returns undefined too.

Comment: See console for errors

Comment: @Deepak Make sure there are no duplicate ID. Is the textarea inside an iframe?

Comment: i tried alert() too. it shows an empty dialog box. even while debugging with firebug it shows m.note = undefined while m.date and other variables are set properly.

Comment: @KK there are no duplicate ids'. I've checked for that many times now.

Comment: Simplify the problem as a test using only the elements you need in a new, very simple page. Perhaps your HTML has a defect? For instance, you could think it's a doublequote, but it could be replaced by your text editor as a smartquote.

Comment: I also recommend debugging in Chrome instead of FF. It's just a better debugger. Rightclick the page and type Inspect Element, click Console, and then type $('#newNoteText').val(); and hit enter. You can also type $('#newNoteText') and hit enter and it will show you the entire value, of which you can expand it and see the subitems inside. That might give you a clue as to what is going on.

Comment: @Volomike it works in a simple page. i've tried that too. only in my application environment the value is returned as undefined. And html has no defect coz it has been double checked. i think jquery is causing some problem

Comment: Your code gives this error in console : "Uncaught ReferenceError: NewNote is not defined"

Comment: Try replacing jQuery with the latest version.

Comment: @kurenaiKunai NewNote is defined n another .js file. i cant add whole application here so added the main parts that concern the problem.

Comment: @Volomike I'm using the latest jquery version and all the subitems in var n are defined with correct values except n.note. problem is arising from the textarea.

Comment: @Deepak Then u will need to run both files through console and see what the error is cause other than the undefined error there seems to be no problem with the code provided here. I made a few tweaks to your code like making n as the new object and adding alert to the snippet and everything works as it should. Added my tweaks as answer below.

Comment: I made a simple version for you and my version shows the code works: https://jsfiddle.net/euwbc2bb/

Comment: Yeah, it works on jsfiddle for me too. i tried the same logic in fiddle and it worked but doesnt work in the application though.

Comment: Are you creating newNoteText dynamically in code, or was it already on the page to begin with?

Comment: Its not dynamically added.

Answer (score 1):

Your NewNote is giving error in console saying NewNote is not defined.

```js
$("#saveNoteBtn").click(function() {

  var n = new Object();
  n.note = $("#newNoteText").val();
  alert(n.note);
  n.date = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", new Date());
  n.name = notesViewModel["NoteCreator"]();

  notesViewModel.Notes.push(n);
  notes.save();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea placeholder="Type note contents here" id="newNoteText"></textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Send" id="saveNoteBtn" name="saveNoteBtn">
```

Comment: NewNote is defined n another .js file. i cant add whole application here so added the main parts that concern the problem.

Comment: Yes, obviously this isn't the answer because NewNote is not provided.

Comment: @Deepak Then u will need to run both files through console and see what the error is cause other than the undefined error there seems to be no problem with the code provided here. I made a few tweaks to your code like making n as the new object and adding alert to the snippet and everything works as it should. Added my tweaks as answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include `js file which defined newNote` immediately after the `jquery` file. Better to test after including those two in `<header>` section